# Need help to approach a question of Mensuration

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Answered: In a cylinderical vessel of diameter 24 cm filled
up with sufficient quantity of water, a solid
spherical ball, of radius 6 cm is completely immersed. Then the increases in height of water.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88851/discussion-on-question-by-sagar-gupta-need-help-to-approach-a-question-of-mensur).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to find the volume of the sphere, which is equivalent to the volume of water displaced:
$$ \frac{4\pi r^3}{3} = \frac{4\pi 6^3}{3} = 288\pi $$
Since the vessel is cylindrical, we can find the increase in height, $h$, using the following formula for the volume of a cylinder:
$$ \pi r^2h = V = 288\pi $$